# Pyspark Split Function for Hours

Tags: split, apache-spark-sql, databricks, pyspark

[Screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qFCp.png)

```
 root
  |-- address: string (nullable = true)
  |-- attributes: map (nullable = true)
  |    |-- key: string
  |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
  |-- business_id: string (nullable = true)
  |-- categories: string (nullable = true)
  |-- city: string (nullable = true)
  |-- hours: map (nullable = true)
  |    |-- key: string
  |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
  |-- is_open: long (nullable = true)
  |-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
  |-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
  |-- name: string (nullable = true)
  |-- postal_code: string (nullable = true)
  |-- review_count: long (nullable = true)
  |-- stars: double (nullable = true)
  |-- state: string (nullable = true)
```

I'm currently working with Yelp's dataset and my objective is to find the total hours a business is open a day/week. From the data, I am able to extract a time range for each day that looks like [9:0, 0:0] for a certain day. How can I use pyspark to get two columns, one for open hour showing [9:0] and one for closing hours showing [0:0]?

This is some code I used to simply show the hours for a business in the dataset.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df_hours = df_MappedBusiness.select(
    "business_id",
    "name",
    f.explode("hours").alias("hourDay","hourValue"), 
    f.split("hourValue", "[-]").alias("split_hours")
).show(50, truncate=False)


Expected Output
---------------

+---------------------------------------------------------------- 
|hourDay  |hourValue  |split_hours   | open_hours   | close_hours
+-----------------------------------------------------------------
|Monday   |9:0-0:0    |[9:0, 0:0]    | [9,0]        | [0,0]       |
```

Comment: Can you please share some data and explain the problem with all input and output you want?

Comment: Hi Manu, the output i would like is another column showing [9:0] with the alias open_hours and another with [0:0] with the alias close_hours so I can use a formula/expression to calculate the total number of hours a business is open per week

Comment: ok, Can you tell me elaborate source data a bit. f.explode("hours").alias("hourDay","hourValue"),  -> Does this contain day and hour value. It would be really good if you can provide some source sample data to imagine the situation. 2-3 rows will do the work.

Comment: Hi Manu, this data is from Yelp's Business data, this is the schema:

Comment: I will update the original post with the schema for the data and a screenshot of what I am working with

Comment: the "hours" data simply gives us the hours of a business that looks like [9:0-17:30, 0:0-0:0,,, 9:0-17:30, 9:0-17:30, 9:0-17:30]

Comment: Pls check if my solution will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for this problem. I looked for Yelp's dataset online and applied the solution on it.

```
from pyspark.sql import  SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("Test").getOrCreate()
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr,col,when,lit
import json

df1=spark.read.json(r"your_data_path")



df_mon=df1.select("business_id", "name",lit("Monday").alias("hourday"),when(col("hours.Monday").isNotNull(),f.split("hours.Monday",'-')[0]).alias("OpenHours"),when(col("hours.Monday").isNotNull(),f.split("hours.Monday",'-')[1]).alias("CloseHours"))
df_tue=df1.select("business_id", "name",lit("Tuesday").alias("hourday"),when(col("hours.Tuesday").isNotNull(),f.split("hours.Tuesday",'-')[0]).alias("OpenHours"),when(col("hours.Tuesday").isNotNull(),f.split("hours.Tuesday",'-')[1]).alias("CloseHours"))
df_wed=df1.select("business_id", "name",lit("Wednesday").alias("hourday"),when(col("hours.Wednesday").isNotNull(),f.split("hours.Wednesday",'-')[0]).alias("OpenHours"),when(col("hours.Wednesday").isNotNull(),f.split("hours.Wednesday",'-')[1]).alias("CloseHours"))
df_thu=df1.select("business_id", "name",lit("Thursday").alias("hourday"),when(col("hours.Thursday").isNotNull(),f.split("hours.Thursday",'-')[0]).alias("OpenHours"),when(col("hours.Thursday").isNotNull(),f.split("hours.Thursday",'-')[1]).alias("CloseHours"))
df_fri=df1.select("business_id", "name",lit("Friday").alias("hourday"),when(col("hours.Friday").isNotNull(),f.split("hours.Friday",'-')[0]).alias("OpenHours"),when(col("hours.Friday").isNotNull(),f.split("hours.Friday",'-')[1]).alias("CloseHours"))
df_sat=df1.select("business_id", "name",lit("Saturday").alias("hourday"),when(col("hours.Saturday").isNotNull(),f.split("hours.Saturday",'-')[0]).alias("OpenHours"),when(col("hours.Saturday").isNotNull(),f.split("hours.Saturday",'-')[1]).alias("CloseHours"))
df_sun=df1.select("business_id", "name",lit("Sunday").alias("hourday"),when(col("hours.Sunday").isNotNull(),f.split("hours.Sunday",'-')[0]).alias("OpenHours"),when(col("hours.Sunday").isNotNull(),f.split("hours.Sunday",'-')[1]).alias("CloseHours"))

df_final=df_mon.unionAll(df_tue).unionAll(df_wed).unionAll(df_thu).unionAll(df_fri).unionAll(df_sat).unionAll(df_sun)

df_final.show(10,False)
```

Let me know if you have any questions on it.

Answer (score 0):

After your call to `pyspark.sql.functions.split`, you’ll have created a `Column` of the `ArrayType` (which further holds strings). To access elements in such as nested column, you would use the same syntax you would with lists and even with Pandas Dataframes, i.e. `split(some_column, some_character)[some_index]`.

Example:

```py
df = (spark.createDataFrame(
    (("shop", "Monday", "9:0-0:0"),
     ("shop", "Tuesday", "12:30-21:30")),
    schema=("shopname", "day_of_week", "opening_hours")))

from pyspark.sql.functions import split

(df
 .withColumn("opens", split(df.opening_hours, "-")[0])
 .withColumn("closes", split(df.opening_hours, "-")[1])
 .show()
 )

+--------+-----------+-------------+-----+------+
|shopname|day_of_week|opening_hours|opens|closes|
+--------+-----------+-------------+-----+------+
|    shop|     Monday|      9:0-0:0|  9:0|   0:0|
|    shop|    Tuesday|  12:30-21:30|12:30| 21:30|
+--------+-----------+-------------+-----+------+
```

Note that your approach will leave you with two columns (the last two I added here) of the StringType(). You’ll likely convert these to numbers (e.g. minutes since midnight?), but then you’ll need to look into possible negatives because "closes at 00:00", actually means closes just before midnight. Anyway, I'll leave that as a challenge.

Comment: Thank you for you help!